# Get cookie's create date and time while developing a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for the first time and want to get the createdAt for a cookie.I went through the cookie documentation at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.

The cookie object does not have any createdAt field.

Specifically I am trying to read facebook's cookie whose name is "c_user".

And i need to get the createdAt value for that cookie.

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: think you need to do some basic cookie research there is no createdAt. What makes you think one should be available?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know what system stores about a cookie is not the creation date but the expiring date. But if the cookies are set by you you can set another cookie which holds creation time or even you can combine your cookie data to include the creation time.

I've tried this code which will gives you all the cookies but according to [cookie spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) and the documentation which is next to impossible.

```js
chrome.cookies.getAll(function(cookies) {
 
});
```